# Does it matter if my XML file has an extension other than .xml?

Tags: xml, file, curl, mime-types, lwp

I'm developing a project that will use XML files to dump data for sharing between servers. Does it matter if I use an extension other than `.xml` in the file name? eg. 'myfile.abc' instead of 'myfile.xml'.

These files would be read by client servers using CURL / LWP commands. Are there any issues with `MIME-TYPES` that might cause the files to be unopenable or unreadable as XML? (They will be W3C compliant XML files)

The reason is we need the files to be distinguishable from other XML files on the server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) specifies nothing about an XML file's name or extension.

However, an application or operating system may rely on a file extension to identify file content type.  There's also no guarantee how any given application would interpret conflicting signals from a file's MIME type and its file extension.

**Recommendation**: Stick with the conventional `.xml` file extension for XML files.  To make "the files to be distinguishable from other XML files on the server," use a suitable naming convention on the base file name instead.

Comment: Isn't that why you can configure your server to interpret extensions to MIME types?

Comment: @Misunderstood: If one is only concerned about HTTP, yes, there are configuration solutions that'll allow desired MIME types to be attributed to any given extension.  My answer addresses concerns in the broader sense that is asked by OP's title question, *Does it matter if my XML file has an extension other than .xml?*.  I maintain that interoperability would be facilitated by naming XML files with `.xml` extensions where possible.

Comment: I do not disagree with you.  I think you know a lot more about this than me (that's not saying much).  So I guess the real question is, what do you think may be wrong with my answer.

Comment: @Misunderstood: You're fine.  Had I thought there was something wrong with your answer, I would have commented; substantially wrong, downvoted.  If you're looking for a tip to improve your answer, maybe add details regarding how you configured your server -- as it stands, it says little more than it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to file extensions generally, not just the .xml extension.

The most common cases where file extensions are used are:

(a) when you double-click on a file in a graphical file explorer/finder, the operating system decides what application to open based on the file extension. You can configure the mapping from file extensions to applications, so you don't have to use ".xml", you can use any extension that's mapped to the appropriate application.

(b) when a web server delivers content in response to an HTTP request, the response contains the content type (media type / MIME type) and this will often be based on the file extension. This information is used by the browser when deciding how to display the content. Again, you can configure the mapping of file extensions to media types in the configuration files of your web server (e.g. Apache).

It's quite normal to use particular file extensions for particular XML vocabularies, e.g. .xsl for XSLT and .xsd for XML Schema. But it will work best if you ensure such extensions are properly configured.

Comment: You answer is not wrong, but it is incomplete, and I thought I could add some additional useful information.

Comment: I reread the question.  The OP was looking more for what could go wrong than how to do it.  I am not easily impressed.  I am impressed with your background.  Not only are you a scholar, but a gentleman too.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure your server to use the MIME type `application/xml` or `text/xml` for an .abc extension.

I just configured my server to consider a .abc to be a `text/xml` file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the question relates to how client servers would parse the file in a (say) CURL command. I wasn't specific enough. Will edit question.